# Surnames with quotes breaking SQL query, how to fix this?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apostrophes are breaking my mysql query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961308/apostrophes-are-breaking-my-mysql-query-in-php)

I asked a friend to test my site and his surname had a ' . O'Rourke so I got error with syntax around Rourke. Obviously caused by the apostrophe.

How do I prevent this from happening so he can register to my site?

```
$name = $user_profile[name];

mysql_select_db("gamedb", $con);

$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO Users (FID, Name, Date) VALUES ('$fid','$name',NOW())";
```

Does escaping solve the issue? I couldn't actually try escaping it since the name is retrieved from the usr facebook account.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to this being a dup of the above, you *really* want to click on the link in the answer to that post regarding SQL Injection.

Comment: This isn't really the first time this has been explained to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880490/how-do-i-retrieve-escaped-strings-from-db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Prepared statements. That'll automatically handle input escaping. The current `INSERT` is open to a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Check out [`mysqli_stmt::prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

Comment: This is the only answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the variables

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Users (
          FID, 
          Name, 
          Date
        ) VALUES (
          '" . mysql_real_escape_string($fid) . "',
          '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "',
          NOW()
        )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the string with:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($user_profile[name]);
```

This prevent [sql injection](http://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&rct=j&q=sql%20injection&ei=KFdgTr28KoqFtgfX9vkS&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `mysql_real_escape_string($sql)` before you insert a row

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` function in php. You can see the details here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php